# Show array in different aspect than Data Band

Tags: report, stimulsoft

I'm using Stimulsoft Designer for the creation of a report, and I have an array of users that I want to display their information. I don't want to use a DataBand because it displays like a database table: one row after another. I want to give the look of the image to every element of the array. Is there a way to do it? Or I just need to stick with DataBand?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I just figured out... I have to insert a DataBand, and then re-arrange / add items within it. And that's it.